# JQuery Validate "extensions" rule not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm using JQuery to validate an HTML form, but the "extension" rule is not working (even though I've included the `additional-methods.js` file. I've tested my other "rules" (that also come from that js file), and those seem to work fine, so I'm not sure why the extension one isn't.

Here is the html/JS code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form method="POST" id="regForm" action="{{ url_for('pipeline') }}">
  <div class="tab">
    <h3>User Assets:</h3>
    <br>
    <label>Interval BED File</label>
    {{ form.target(placeholder="(e.g. Exome-NGv3.bed)...", oninput="this.className = ''") }}
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label>Sentieon Package Name</label>
        {{ form.sentieon_package_name(placeholder="(e.g. sentieon-genomics-201711.01.tar.gz)...", oninput="this.className = ''") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label>Sentieon License Name</label>
        {{ form.sentieon_license_name(placeholder="(e.g mylicense.lic)...", oninput="this.className = ''") }}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#regForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            sentieon_package_name: {
                required: true,
                extension: "tar|tar.gz"
            },
            sentieon_license_name: {
                required: true,
                extension: "lic"
            },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that in line 2 of your code, you have an opened `<script>` tag. This is what is causing your problems. Change this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

And all your problems will be fixed.

Comment: Oh sorry, it doesn't look like that in my actual script, I guess I added that open `<script>` tag in accidentally when I copied my code to the question. So it's definitely not from that!